# Should I go to Switzerland from Paris?

Tags: schengen, paris, switzerland

I'm going to Paris for a conference from 14th to 18th September, sponsored by an organization. The conference is on 15th and 16th, I have 17th and 18th full days free. (Departing flight is on 18th at 10pm). I will probably never come in this area again since i can't afford. I was wondering if I should check Paris and the museums on 14th and evenings of 15th, 16th, and leave for Switzerland on 17th? And come back on 18th morning. Is that worth it?

Comment: Have you considered a day trip to locations near Paris. For example, Chartres and/or Versailles?

Comment: It is definitely possible to get a quick flight from Paris to many places in Switzerland, therefore your plan sounds perfectly feasible. But what will you do if you buy your ticket now, get to Paris, and it captivates you so much that you want to give it those 2 free days? Switzerland is of course very nice too, but also expensive, so keep that in mind in terms of lodging and food expenses.

Comment: Switzerland is not in the area of Paris. Its on the other side of France. If you must go to another country surely Belgium is the more sensible choice?

Comment: @theotherone Maybe OP is from Australia or N-America or Siberia and thinks anything within 1000 km is "close".

Comment: Whether or not it's up to you is purely a matter of your opinion. We can't answer that.

Comment: I suggest not. Paris is much less expensive than Switzerland. And has more than enough museums to keep you busy. Please note there is a [museum pass](http://en.parismuseumpass.com/) that may save you money.

Comment: From Paris, it takes a high-speed train between 3 hours (Basel) to 4 hours (Zurich). If the conference was further in the future, I'd suggest moving your return to depart from the Swiss city. As it is, that's a good bit of travelling to get there & back.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it's worth it.

Depending where in Switzerland you're going, it will take at least three hours each way by train, and potentially much longer (5+ hours to Interlaken, for example). And that's only the time between the train stations; you'll need time on each end to get to/from the stations. You could easily spend more time going back and forth than actually seeing things in Switzerland.

It will also involve a fair amount of expense. A round trip by train (bus would be cheaper, but would take up all your available time) on those dates will likely cost over €200 for, if you start early enough in the morning, maybe six hours of usable sightseeing time in Switzerland. You may be able to get a cheaper flight to some places in Switzerland, though again, consider the time taken for the entire journey, not just the flight time.

I personally like taking costly day trips that don't make a ton of logical sense, and I wouldn't do this one. You're only giving yourself one full day and two evenings in Paris. Given the number of [things you could see and do in Paris](https://www.ricksteves.com/europe/france/paris) (see "at a glance"), that's not much at all. I'd spend the time you have left in Paris, not jumping back and forth, or consider [a shorter day trip from Paris](http://www.rearviewmirror.tv/the-complete-list-of-day-trips-from-paris/) if you really want to go somewhere else.